# Can I remove the lines in the Notes.app and change the line spacing?

Tags: customization, macos, notes.app

The only reason I use the Notes.app and not Stickies.app is iCloud sync.

I enjoy the **customization (colors, fonts, minimized view)** and **minimalism (plain background, thin borders)** of Stickies over the skeuomorphismic approach which generally requires much more space on the desktop.

- How can I safely remove the background lines and change the line spacing in Notes.app?

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching for keys for hidden preferences with `strings /Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes | grep`, but didn't find anything.

There's no graphics for the grid lines, because they're just solid lines and their height depends on the font size. You can almost get rid of the grid lines by replacing paper.png with a solid color, but there's a light gradient drawn over it.

[image]

I also tried adding shortcuts for orderFrontSpacingPanel: and setLineHeightMultiplier: in DefaultKeyBinding.dict, but they didn't have any effect.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there doesn't seem to be an acceptable way of tweaking this application. Still, thank you *very* much for taking the time to look into this!